# Silverlight: Difficulty with WebClient

Tags: silverlight, json, rest, windows-phone-7, webclient

I'm having a really weird issue. I must be doing something really obvious that is wrong, but I can't see it. I'm building a wp7 app which currently runs in the emulator.

I have a URL that returns JSON. I visit this URL in my browser and verify that it works.

I get the data from this URL in Silverlight using `WebClient`. When I get the result, it's all the same - except one of the JSON fields is gone.

How is this possible? I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. What could cause inconsistencies between the way JSON looks in a web browser v. a `WebClient` result in the wp7 emulator?

Here's the code:

```
            downloadData(STORIES_URL + vid,
                delegate(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
                {
                    data_StoryDownloadCompleted(sender, e, _sectionStories[vid], STORIES_URL + vid);
                });

    static void data_StoryDownloadCompleted(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e, ObservableCollection<Story> results, string uri)
    {
        if (e.Error != null)
        {
            throw e.Error;
        }

        JObject data = JObject.Parse(e.Result);
        // ...
    }
```

What could I be doing wrong?

Comment: i presume the raw JSON data is the same coming back,i.e. e.Result is the same, and JObject.Parse is not doing its deserialize as you'd expect?

Comment: No, actually, `e.Result` is *not* the same. That's what freaks me out/makes me think I'm doing something really stupid.

Comment: Are the accept headers different between the two clients?

Comment: hm, that is weird. e.Result is just the straight output from the Webclient? I'm fairly certain it wouldnt strip out a field in the response just for the sake of it. unless your doing some sort of transform between the webclient response, i'd install fiddler and have a look at the raw HTTP.

Answer (score 0):

Can you capture both requests/responses (from browser and from Silverlight) in a tool like Fiddler and compare them? Specifically, watch for any difference in HTTP headers in the requests.

Then (if you're using Fiddler) you can tweak the Silverlight request by adjusting headers one by one to make it look like the browser request, until you find the one that makes the difference.

Comment: I downloaded Fiddler2, but the requests from the emulator don't show up. Am I using it wrong?

Comment: Are the requests going to "localhost"? If so, there are special instructions on setting up Fiddler, see Fiddler docs